# Is there a way to add a body on destroy method using the json_api_client gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

I need to add a body on default destroy method, as a follow:
DELETE /path/{id}, body: {}

Googling around, I couldn't find an answer that came close to the solution I need. Has anyone done something similar?

According to the jsonapi standard documentation, this conforms to the spec: https://jsonapi.org/format/.

"Note: RFC 7231 specifies that a DELETE request may include a body, but that a server may reject the request. This spec defines the semantics of a server, and we are defining its semantics for JSON:API."

```
def destroy(params = {})      
    self.class.connection.delete(self.class.path + "/#{id}", body: params.to_json)
 end
```

Comment: Important point: I'm using the json_api_client gem for that.

Comment: What is `self.class.connection`? We need a few more details here or we will be unable to assist.

Comment: Updating: After further research, I decided against this approach, as in the source code for the 'json_api_client' gem, any body in get or delete requests is disregarded. To go that way, I would have to proceed with overriding the code, which wouldn't sound good with the patterns. Thanks @engineersmnky.